# Will publishing a new update on google play remove any sqlite3 database already install on a customer device?

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to publish my first app. As my app will use a sqlite3 database on the customers smart device. I am just wondering if I release any future updates will it remove and replace the existing database. I wouldn't want my customer to have to data entry again after they install a new update.

I have tested this out by deploying my app on some test devices using Android Studio 0.4.6. But I just want to make sure.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: it depends how you creating it... db file will be not deleteted but your app can override this file on first start after upgrade ... you didn't tell us if: you are using SQLiteOpenHelper or you are copying db from assets

Comment: Yes, I have just SQLiteOpenHepler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, all the persistence storage including Sqlite databases, shared preferences and files are not affected by an app upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Unless or until the `cache` of the device is cleared, the persistence storage remains there. so there are two cases

**If the cache is being cleared**

then all the data need to be populated again

**If cache is not cleared**

then you do not worry :)